# Service management page is not working in CAS - 3.4.12.1

Tags: tomcat7, single-sign-on, cas

Trying to open this page - https://:8443/cas/services/manage.html - it redirects to CAS Login Page- after putting the username/password it redirects to **https://:8443/cas/services/j_acegi_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-10-Lhl4toafxJdCZLu7gkLN-** and give me an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Please help.

Comment: need more information. Is your cas server working in the first place without any issues? Is the link https://:8443/cas working when you login?

Comment: Yes, my CAS login is working fine and even now I am able to get the service management page after I added the certificates in the cacerts. But now I am facing a different issue altogether, the application I am going to authenticate through CAS is not getting authenticated and stops at - Application Not Authorized to Use CAS
The application you attempted to authenticate to is not authorized to use CAS.
Please suggest. I have already added URLs in Service Management still no success.